# Request a resource with `/` into path parameter

Tags: karate

I have to request a resource with a `/` character inside a path parameter that i'm unable to request with karate.

For example, my resource id is `aaa/bbb` and the corresponding URL is: `http://localhost/resource/aaa%2Fbbb`

If I request with

```
Given url http://localhost/resource
And path 'aaa/bbb'
```

karate will request `http://localhost/resource/aaa/bbb`

If I request with

```
Given url http://localhost/resource
And path 'aaa%2Fbbb'
```

karate will request `http://localhost/resource/aaa%252Fbbb`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate is following the [HTTP specs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) and it sounds like you have a very badly designed API. Really ? You need a `/` character in a path !?

Anyway here is [your solution](https://github.com/intuit/karate#path):

```
Given url 'http://localhost/resource/aaa%2Fbbb'
```

Yes, it's that simple.